# How to Launch a PDF from a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) Web Application

Tags: javascript, windows, pdf, uwp

I've converted an existing web application (HTML5, JS, CSS, etc.) into a Windows UWP app so that (hopefully) I can distribute it via the Windows Store to Surface Hubs so it can run offline. Everything is working fine, except PDF viewing. If I open a PDF in a new window, the Edge-based browser window simply crashes. If I open an IFRAME and load PDFJS into it, that also crashes. What I'd really like to do is just hand off the PDF to the operating system so the user can view it in whatever PDF viewer they have installed.

I've found some windows-specific Javascript APIs that seem promising, but I cannot get them to work. For example:

```
 Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(
   new Windows.Foundation.Uri(
     "file:///"+
     Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.path
       .replace(/\//g,"/")+"/app/"+url)).then(function(success) {
                if (!success) {
```

That generates a file:// URL that I can copy into Edge and it shows the PDF, so I know the URL stuff is right. However, in the application it does nothing.

If I pass an https:// URL into that launchUriAsync function, that works. So it appears that function just doesn't like file:// URLs.

I also tried this:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(url).then(
  function(file) { Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file) })
```

That didn't work either. Again, no error. It just didn't do anything.

Any ideas of other things I could try?

-- Update --

See the accepted answer. Here is the code I ended up using. (Note that all my files are in a subfolder called "app"):

```
if (location.href.match(/^ms-appx:/)) {
        url = url.replace(/\?.+/, "");
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(("app/" + url).replace(/\//g,"\\")).then(
            function (file) {
                var fn = performance.now()+url.replace(/^.+\./, ".");
                file.copyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.temporaryFolder,
                    fn).then(
                    function (file2) {
                        Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file2)
                    })
            });
        return;
    }
```

Turns out you have to turn the / into \ or it won't find the file. And copyAsync refuses to overwrite, so I just use performance.now to ensure I always use a new file name. (In my application, the source file names of the PDFs are auto-generated anyway.) If you wanted to keep the filename, you'd have to add a bunch of code to check whether it's already there, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaunchFileAsync is the right API to use here. You can't launch a file directly from the install directory because it is protected. You need to copy it first to a location that is accessible for the other app (e.g. your PDF viewer). Use StorageFile.CopyAsync to make a copy in the desired location.

Official SDK sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching

Comment: This comment in that C# sample is telling: "Can't launch files directly from install folder so copy it over to temporary folder first". I'll see if I can figure out how to do that copy in a javascript web app.

Comment: Correct, you need to copy from the install location. You can use StorageFile.CopyAsync for that. I'll edit my answer to capture that detail.

Comment: I'll update my question to show the code I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

I just thought I'd add a variation on this answer, which combines some details from above with [this info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/68880fa3-7a6b-407c-8ed3-566150d34ac0/uwp-winjs-writing-a-blob-to-a-file-in-a-uwp-js-app) about saving a blob as a file in a JavaScript app. My case is that I have a BLOB that represents the data for an epub file, and because of the UWP content security policy, it's not possible simply to force a click on a URL created from the BLOB (that "simple" method is explicitly blocked in UWP, even though it works in Edge). Here is the code that worked for me:

```
// Copy BLOB to downloads folder and launch from there in Edge
// First create an empty file in the folder
Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.createFileAsync(filename,
    Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName).then(
    function (file) {
    // Open the returned dummy file in order to copy the data to it 
    file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite).then(function (output) {
        // Get the InputStream stream from the blob object 
        var input = blob.msDetachStream();
        // Copy the stream from the blob to the File stream 
        Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output).then(
        function () {
            output.flushAsync().done(function () {
                input.close();
                output.close();
                Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Note that `CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName` handles the file renaming automatically, so I don't need to fiddle with `performance.now()` as in the answer above.

Just to add that one of the things that's so difficult about UWP app development, especially in JavaScript, is how hard it is to find coherent information. It took me hours and hours to put the above together from snippets and post replies, following false paths and incomplete MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the PDF APIs https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument/js

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/PdfDocument/js/js/scenario1-render.js

Are you simply just trying to render a PDF file?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to just launch it in whatever PDF viewer the user has installed. That's what I do in my Electron-based apps, and it's worked very well. Once they have the PDF, they can view it, print it, email it, save it someplace outside the application. Same deal in my mobile apps. I just throw it to QuickLook on iOS, or throw it to whatever PDF viewer they have on Android.

Writing a whole mess of code to render the PDF could be a fallback if launching the file is impossible. But why should launching the file be impossible? That's kind of nuts.