# Can't open help file as Windows 10 Universal application

Tags: mfc, windows-10-universal, chm, desktop-bridge

I've just used [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) to package three MFC applications for uploading to the Windows Store.

They all work fine but for some reason one of them is unable to open the help file. (Help works fine in the other two applications.)

The problem application works perfectly when run from Visual Studio or by double clicking the executable. But accessing help gives me the following error after being installed from the test AppX package.

> Failed to launch help.

I'm able to use Task Manager to locate the installed application location and confirmed that it does contain my help file. In addition, I added code to display the path of the help file on start up, and it displays the correct help path! But no matter what I do, my application cannot bring up help.

Does anyone know if there is anything about the limited privileges of being installed as a Windows 10 app that could somehow limit access to the help file? Or can anyone suggest how to get past the completely useless error message above to get a hint about why it is failing?

Comment: Where is the file located and how are you trying to open/launch it?

Comment: The help file is in the same folder as the executable. I have a command handler in my app class that delegates to CWinApp::OnHelp.

Comment: Try setting the current working directory to that path. If it's trying to open the file from current working directory then it won't work in the converted app, because that path is pointing elsewhere.

Comment: I modified the code to open a message box that displays the value of m_pszHelpFilePath. And I verified it has the correct value. That is, it reflects the actual path where the help file is found. Makes me think it finds the help file but is having trouble loading it. If only the error message was a little more informative.

Comment: What process is actually opening the help file? Keep in mind that only processes that run in the context of your app package have access to your app's install directory.

Comment: My app is a single executable (a dialog-based MFC application) and a help (CHM) file. That's all. The executable has the code to load the help file.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the .chm file get launched with hh.exe? That process is not part of your package and won't be able to access your install folder. Try copying the .chm file to %temp% or some other location that hh.exe can access and see if it addresses the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend building a small simple CHM and try your code calling the CHM again. I think it's a What this or a F1 call Cousine this issue - please check for special characters in filenames e.g. # or blanks. Try a Google search for **Failed to launch Help** too

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: I believe under the covers the help file is launch with an API call (HtmlHelp, or something like that). It's not possible to copy the file from the installed directory. I don't have rights. I have my original help file and, as indicated, it works fine.

Comment: @help-info.de: As indicated previously, the CHM files works just fine. Only after being installed as a Universal Windows 10 app is there an issue. Also, I cannot control the path where it gets installed or the characters in that path. And, as also indicated previously, the file path being used matches the actual path.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that at runtime (like on launch) your app makes a copy of the .chm file in an accessible location (e.g. %TEMP%). Then you change m_pszHelpFilePath to point to that new location. Now the HtmlHelp API should be able to pick it up from the new location.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: I doubt I have rights to copy that file. Apps installed as Univeral apps are somewhat restricted. I suppose I could try it. But to be honest, I'm not sure what that would tell me if it made any difference. My other two apps have help and they work fine. So I could try it later today but it really doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Your app does have access to your install folder (otherwise it could not load its DLLs, etc.). Other processes cannot access your install folder though, hence the help viewer process fails to load it. This is by design in the modern app model to ensure isolation. By copying it to an accessible location you enable the help viewer to actually load the file. If this doesn't help, please share a repro, so we can do more than psychic debugging :-)

Comment: Btw, here is a similar question about opening a PDF file from the install location, with essentially the same answer as solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900180/how-to-launch-a-pdf-from-a-uwp-universal-windows-platform-web-application/45906230#45906230

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: Actually, that works. I copied the CHM file to the temp directory and set `m_pszHelpFilePath` to the new location, and help works!!! Running some more tests...

Comment: Great, I have posted this as answer now. Please confirm when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the .chm file that contains your help content is located in your applications install folder. In the modern Windows app model that folder is locked down so that only processes that are part of your app package can access it. With the MFC framework, however, the help viewer that gets invoked is not part of your package - therefore it can't access the .chm file.

Solution is for your app at runtime (e.g. right after launch) to make a copy of the .chm file in an accessible location (e.g. %TEMP%) and update m_pszHelpFilePath to point to that location. Now the help viewer process should be able to load the help successfully.

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me. But I still don't see the issue as resolved. First, as I mentioned in my OP, i have three such programs. And help is working fine in the other two. Second, it would hardly be acceptable that help doesn't work in the new app model. The Windows HtmlHelp() API should work! And for all but one of my apps, it does.

Comment: The MFC model was invented 25 years ago, in a time when software was bought in a box, everyone was admin, the internet and security was not a thing. This resulted in many problem that exist today: DLL hell, registry rot, security and privacy concerns, just to mention a few. When moving an app from that era we need to apply the rules from the new model, which in some cases will require you to make a few code changes, like in this case. I'll be happy to take a look at why help in your other apps worked without changes. Are those already in the Store, so I can take a look?

Comment: Windows is old too. And the Windows API needs to work to keep Windows viable. And I think help is still important (even though Microsoft doesn't seem to as much). My other apps are not yet live on the store and won't be free when they are. I do have a Microsoft contact that has been helping me with the Desktop Bridge. I think he will look at this further. I'd love to have anyone else take a look, but I'd probably need to share information and bits that would not be appropriate here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Tell your Microsoft contact to reach out to me and we can follow up offline. I am the Program Manager for the Desktop Bridge. Help certainly continues to be supported in Windows, but the way apps are using it needs to comply with the rules of the modern app model. This may require app code changes. We have always said in our documentation/presentations that apps moving on the Desktop Bridge may have to make compatible code changes to comply with the app model.

Comment: Oh, you're the Program Manager for Desktop Bridge? I'm working with Matteo in Italy. I'll mention this to him. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears this issue has been dropped because it was not apparent to the folks looking into it what the problem is. I have established that there is not an inherent problem with CHM files in the same directory as the app, because it works fine with my other apps. I'm not sure why Microsoft made this work in such a restricted way. But it looks like they restricted my app from working correctly.