# Problems with code needed to open pdf file on UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to display a pdf when a button is clicked on a UWP app. I found some examples on internet and i'm trying to apply the following code:

```
String fileUrl = "ms-appx:///Pics/normes.pdf";
Windows.System.LauncherOptions options = new 
Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(fileUrl), options);
```

This code is supposed to open the pdf file but it does not. It opens the program that will show the pdf but then shows nothing. It is a desktop app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Launch a PDF from a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900180/how-to-launch-a-pdf-from-a-uwp-universal-windows-platform-web-application)

Comment: It isn't the same case.

Comment: While it may look different it's the same case Open PDF from UWP. It does not matter which language projection you use. UWP is a COM technology under the hood. Answer in that thread tells about C# case BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file) instead of `LaunchUriAsync` method.

```
String fileUrl = "ms-appx:///Assets/Sample.pdf";
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(fileUrl));
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a webview control, and set the Source property to a string variable that contains the url you wish to use.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="WebViewPanel">
            <WebView x:Name="webView" 
                     Source="{Binding PageLink, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```